Oracle SQL query is not using index
I'm running the below query in my Oracle DB. The index trunc(create_date) is created on the table ORDERS. But the below query is not using the index when I run it.
SELECT ITEM, MAX("Orders") AS OP_ORD, MAX("SHIP") AS SHIP
FROM  ORDERS
WHERE  trunc(create_date) in(
        SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-6-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
         union
        SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-5-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
         union
        SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-4-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
         union
        SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-3-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
  )
GROUP BY ITEM

But if I'm removing the last query from the subquery like below, then it will use the index
SELECT ITEM, MAX("Orders") AS OP_ORD, MAX("SHIP") AS SHIP
FROM  ORDERS
WHERE  trunc(create_date) in(
       SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-6-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
         union
       SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-5-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL
         union
       SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-4-(select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual) FROM DUAL                  
)
GROUP BY ITEM

Any idea why this is not using the index?

Which days of the week are you expecting to select? to_char(sysdate, 'd') produces different output depending on what the NLS_TERRITORY setting is. Approximately, the 1st day of the week is: Monday in Europe; Sunday in America; Saturday in West Asia; and Friday in Bangladesh. So your code is going to give different output in different parts of the world.

@MT0 There is no issue with the to_char(sysdate, 'd') statement, it is working as expected. The issue is with the index, which is not being used

Your query fails with ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. I assume SELECT ITEM, ... should be SELECT ITEM_ID, ... otherwise you need to GROUP BY item_id, item.

As for "There is no issue" - see fiddle. There may be "no issue" for you if you always use the same NLS_TERRITORY settings but there is an issue if other people use your code around the world.

Syntax and functionality issues aside, what are the optimizer's cardinality estimates?  What are the actual cardinalities?  It sounds like the optimizer is expecting that the index would be more efficient if it was retrieving 3 days worth of data and a table scan would be more efficient if it was retrieving 4 days worth of data.  That may or may not be accurate.  Perhaps statistics are stale and you've added a lot of data since you last gathered stats.

As a side note : You'd better prefer using a hierarchical query in order to get rid of the multiple select statements which are subqueries of the current queries.

Index use is not always the right choice. Oracle is trying to be intelligent, using indexes only when it thinks it faster than a full table scan. A date range is a classic situation where Oracle can easily flip between preferring one access method over the other, depending on the range and its knowledge of min/max date values in its statistics.
You'd be better off:

Replace the TRUNC(create_date) with just a normal index on create_date, then rewrite your date logic (using comparison operators <,>, between, etc.) to avoid using the TRUNC operator on the column, as MT0 demonstrated. Oracle has a very hard time figuring out what to expect once you apply a function to a predicate column like that.

If when Oracle prefers a full table scan you find that it's slower than it should be, either update statistics (doesn't always work) or hint the query:
SELECT /*+ INDEX(orders) */ ITEM, MAX("Orders") AS OP_ORD, MAX("SHIP") AS SHIP
  FROM  ORDERS
 WHERE create_date  . . .


If the full scan is in fact faster, then let Oracle do the full scan and thank it for being so smart.

For maximum speed when you have a very large table, range partition the table by create_date with an interval of 1 day, then drop your index. Those full scans will become full scans of only the partitions containing your dates. That'll be much faster than using indexes for a query like this. You can then add some parallelism to the query to make those full partition scans screaming fast. Chances are you'll rarely want to use an index on a date column again.


As a general rule when writing SQL, minimize your use of subqueries, especially nested ones, and avoid using TO_CHAR to do date arithmetic. That's really meant for visual presentation only. Also avoid TRUNC unless it's really necessary, and then only on the side opposite the column you are accessing.

I tried hints, but it is still not using it. It is clear that the best way is index scan. Because with index the query takes less than 5minutes, without index it takes near to four hours

Assuming that (based on your profile) your NLS_TERRITORY = 'India' and you are trying to select rows from Sunday two weeks ago through to either Tuesday or Wednesday of last week then you can filter the results without using TRUNC on the create_date column or using IN by, instead, filtering on a range:
SELECT ITEM_ID,
       MAX("Orders") AS OP_ORD,
       MAX("SHIP") AS SHIP
FROM   ORDERS
WHERE  create_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '8' DAY
AND    create_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '4' DAY
GROUP BY ITEM_ID

This would/may use an index on the underlying create_date column rather than the function-based TRUNC(create_date) index .
(Note: Using TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') will always give midnight of the most-recent Monday, the start of the ISO week, regardless of what settings the user has. TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd') will give different results depending on the NLS_TERRITORY settings of the session for the user performing the query - i.e. two different users can get different results using TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd') for exactly the same query if their NLS_TERRITORY session settings are different.)
You could equally write your query as:
SELECT ITEM_ID,
       MAX("Orders") AS OP_ORD,
       MAX("SHIP") AS SHIP
FROM   ORDERS
WHERE  TRUNC(create_date) IN (
         TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '8' DAY,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '6' DAY,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '5' DAY
       )
GROUP BY ITEM_ID

Which both give the same output irrespective of the NLS_TERRITORY setting and give different EXPLAIN PLANs to your query - fiddle (the EXPLAIN PLANs are shown at the end of the fiddle).

Any idea why this is not using the index?

The optimiser will look at the query and determine an execution plan that, based on the available statistics and other heuristics, it determines is the "best". For three days of data it may determine that filtering based on the index and then retrieving the corresponding rows which contain the other column data is most efficient. However, for four days, it may determine that, due to the increased volume of data, it is less efficient to use an index and is actually more efficient to just perform a table scan and ignore the index.
As Justin Cave points out in his comment:

"That [decision by the optimiser] may or may not be accurate. Perhaps statistics are stale and you've added a lot of data since you last gathered stats."

You may then:

need to gather new statistics on your table which may change the plan that the optimiser chooses; or
accept that the optimiser may be correct and using an index is less efficient than a table scan; or
try using hints to force the index to be used.

